# Find top 5 word lengths in a text

Tags: list, function, python-3.x, testing, string-length

I'm trying to write a program that takes two functions:

1. **count_word_lengths** which takes the argument **text**, a string of text, and returns a default dictionary that records the count for each word length. An example call to this function:
2. **top5_lengths** which takes the same argument **text** and returns a list of the top 5 word lengths.

Note: that in the event that
two lengths have the same frequency, they should be sorted in descending order. Also, if there are fewer than 5 word lengths it should return a shorter list of the sorted word lengths.

Example calls to **count_word_lengths**:

```
count_word_lengths("one one was a racehorse two two was one too"):
     defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 1, 3: 8, 9: 1})
```

Example calls to **top5_lengths**:

```
top5_lengths("one one was a racehorse two two was one too")
    [3, 9, 1]

top5_lengths("feather feather feather chicken feather")
    [7]

top5_lengths("the swift green fox jumped over a cool cat")
    [3, 5, 4, 6, 1]
```

My current code is this, and seems to output all these calls, however it is failing a hidden test. What type of input am I not considering? Is my code actually behaving correctly? If not, how could I fix this?

```
from collections import defaultdict

length_tally = defaultdict(int)
final_list = []

def count_word_lengths(text):
    words = text.split(' ')

    for word in words:
        length_tally[len(word)] += 1

    return length_tally


def top5_word_lengths(text):
    frequencies = count_word_lengths(text)
    list_of_frequencies = frequencies.items()
    flipped = [(t[1], t[0]) for t in list_of_frequencies]
    sorted_flipped = sorted(flipped)
    reversed_sorted_flipped = sorted_flipped[::-1]


    for item in reversed_sorted_flipped:
        final_list.append(item[1])

    return final_list
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that you do not account for an empty string. That would cause count() to return null/undefined. Also you can use iteritems() during list comprehension to get the key and value from a dict like `for k,v in dict.iteritems():`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Python guy, but I can see a few things that might cause issues.

- You keep referring to `top5_lengths`, but your code has a function called `top5_word_lengths`.
- You use a function called `count_lengths` that isn't defined anywhere.

Fix these and see what happens!

**Edit**:
This shouldn't impact your code, but it's not great practice for your functions to update variables outside their scope. You probably want to move the variable assignments at the top to functions where they're used.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but an alternative way of tracking words instead of just lengths:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def count_words_by_length(text):
   words = [(len(word),word) for word in text.split(" ")]
   d = defaultdict(list)
   for k, v in words:
      d[k].append(v)
   return d


def top_words(dict, how_many):
    return [{"word_length": length, "num_words": len(words)} for length, words in dict.items()[-how_many:]]
```

Use as follows:

```
my_dict = count_words_by_length('hello sir this is a beautiful day right')
my_top_words = num_top_words_by_length(my_dict, 5)

print(my_top_words)
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
[{'word_length': 9, 'num_words': 1}]
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: ['a'], 2: ['is'], 3: ['sir', 'day'], 4: ['this'], 5: ['hello', 'right'], 9: ['beautiful']})
```